# Mongodb index for 2 fields where one is using $gt and $lt

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So I have a collection with 4 million documents (and counting)...

I noticed my query for checking if the user already played a match on current day is getting very slow.

Currently I have this:

```
const currentDate = new Date();
const startDate = new Date(currentDate).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
const endDate = new Date(currentDate).setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
// user is just a string
const didAlreadySubmit = await Match.find({ user: req.body.user, submittedAt: { $gte: startDate, $lt: endDate } }).exec();
```

What kind of index should I make to make this query a lot faster, or are there any other optimizing tips for this? (currently it takes about 5-7s to execute).

Also, how do I implement this new index in currently production database?

Comment: You can create a CompoundIndex  using both the startDate and EndDate.
MongoDB will create a new index on those two fields.

Comment: I don't have startDate and endDate in DB. Only "submittedAt". I am calculating start and end dates when the route is hit, and looking in db if user did already submitted a score on current day.

Comment: Do you have already an index on the submittedAt? If not you can create it, then compare the response time.